# API on react behave different on console.log

Tags: reactjs, api, flask

I have this flask api that can be access on the endpoint localhost:5000/todo and the response will be

```
    [
        {
            "complete": true,
            "text": "Todo 1",
            "user_id": 5
         },
         {
            "complete": true,
             "text": "Noise polution",
             "user_id": 5
         },
    ]
```

Then I am consuming this endpoint on react.

**App.js**

```
 function App() {

  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  const getTodo = () => {
    const url = "http://localhost:5000/todo"
    axios.get(url)
      .then(res => {
        setTodos(res.data)
        console.log(res)
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getTodo();
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <Todo todos={todos} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

on the todo component

```
    function Todo = ({ todos }) ...
    console.log(todos)
```

I get

blank bracket before the list of todo

here the screenshot [image]

I don't know where that bracket comes from before the actual list, does anybody encounter this and how to fix it? I am only learning react on this point.

Comment: *"I don't know where that bracket comes from"* - `useState([]);`?

Comment: notice you're fetcing the data in componentDidMount e.g after the component mounted witch means in first render it takes the default todos state value useState( [ ] )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The todos gets logged twice. Once the component is initially logged when it is empty array, since you have initialized it as empty array with useState hook.

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]); // Initialized with []
```

Now, when axios fetches the result, todos is assigned the response which causes a change in the state and the component is re-rendered. This causes the second console log to appear with the list.